# Radio button selection is not working in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have radio buttons for male and female. I am making male as checked by default. My code working as expected in the chrome. In IE whenever page loads, male will be selected by default but i am not able to click on female. This happens only in ie. Below is my code.

```
<div class="inputblock gender">
  <label class="inputblock-label">{{ 'Gender' | translate }}</label>
  <label for="male" class="male">
    {{ 'Male' | translate }}
    <span class="input-icon"><img src="images/male-icon.png"></span>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="selector" ng-model="Gender" value="M">
    <span class="selector-male"></span>
  </label>
  <label for="female" class="female">
    {{ 'Female' | translate }}
    <span class="input-icon"><img src="images/female-icon.png"></span>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="selector" ng-model="Gender" value="F">
    <span class="selector-female"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

In js file i am setting `$scope.Gender = "M";` to select male as selected when the page loads. I am not able to change gender in only IE. I am finding very hard to find out why this is happening? May i gt some help here to fix? any help would be appreciated. Thank you..

Comment: Could you please create a plnkr. that would be more help to understand the problem.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Thank you. I am using IE version 11.

Comment: I would omit the `name="selector"` attributes. They are not required when using AngularJS to control the model and only serve to set the property name in the parent `form` object. You may be creating a conflict by setting the same name on both controls

Comment: I am getting error when i emit name property. Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console for IE?

Comment: Hi Vivz, I am not getting any error in console(IE11).

Comment: Your code seems to be working in IE. I tested it now but without the translate. Maybe try removing all things related to angular translate from your code to verify whether this might be the cause for the problem

Comment: thank you. May i know what exactly i should remove?